# Getting the contents of an array for a custom XML datatype in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, json, xml, powershell, api

I am using the following code to get:

```
taskAnswers: [{key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"},…]0: {key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"}

# Define output stream type
    [OutputType([object])]

    # Define runbook input params
    Param
    (
        # API Params
        #[Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
        [string] $taskId 

}

    # Add XMLMC params
    Add-HB-Param "taskId" $taskId $false
    
   # Invoke XMLMC call, output returned as PSObject
   $xmlmcOutput = Invoke-HB-XMLMC "task" "taskGetInfo"
   $exceptionName = "" 
   $exceptionSummary = ""
   
    # Read output status
    if($xmlmcOutput.status -eq "ok") {
    if($xmlmcOutput.params.title -and $xmlmcOutput.params.title -ne ""){
            $title = $xmlmcOutput.params.title
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
        }
        if($xmlmcOutput.params.options -and $xmlmcOutput.params.options -ne ""){
            $options = $xmlmcOutput.params.options
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
            }
            if($xmlmcOutput.params.createdOn -and $xmlmcOutput.params.createdOn -ne ""){
            $createdOn = $xmlmcOutput.params.createdOn
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
        }
        if($xmlmcOutput.params.createdBy -and $xmlmcOutput.params.createdBy -ne ""){
            $createdBy = $xmlmcOutput.params.createdBy
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
        }
        if($xmlmcOutput.params.owner -and $xmlmcOutput.params.owner -ne ""){
            $owner = $xmlmcOutput.params.owner
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
        }
        if($xmlmcOutput.params.outcomes -and $xmlmcOutput.params.outcomes -ne ""){
            $outcomes = $xmlmcOutput.params.outcomes
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
        }
        if($xmlmcOutput.params.taskAnswers -and $xmlmcOutput.params.taskAnswers -ne ""){
            $taskAnswers = $xmlmcOutput.params.taskAnswers
            $requestWarnings = $xmlmcOutput.params.warnings
        }
        }
    
    # Build resultObject to write to output
    $resultObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Status = $xmlmcOutput.status
        Error = $xmlmcOutput.error
        ExceptionName = $exceptionName
        ExceptionSummary = $exceptionSummary
        title = $title
        options = $options
        createdOn = $createdOn
        createdBy = $createdBy
        owner = $owner
        outcomes = $outcomes
        taskAnswers = $taskAnswers
        }

    if($resultObject.Status -ne "ok" -or $exceptionName -ne ""){
        Write-Error $resultObject
    } else {
        Write-Output $resultObject
        }
```

I can see that taskAnswers is an array, but I am struggling to return:

I've tried a PSCustomObject with with a ForEach-Object to loop through the array, but this doesn't return any results.

Having run

`Get-Member -InputObject $resultObject`, I can see that taskAnswers is Boolean so with only return true or false.

Comment: "*I can see that taskAnswers is an array.*" How? Please add that to the question, also add the actual result of `Get-Member -InputObject $resultObject`. Btw `[{key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"},…]0: {key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"}` looks like an invalid json string of and array or dictionary. Please elobate (in the question) what this is/how it is retrieved.

Comment: I pulled taskAnswers: [{key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"},…]0: {key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"} from inspect element in Google Chrome.

Comment: TaskAnswers does look like a json string, so try using `$taskAnswers = ConvertFrom-Json $xmlmcOutput.params.taskAnswers`, then look at the object? It could be the original json wasn't processed to the right depth by `Invoke-HB-XMLMC` - Try running it in a newer powershell version? As of 6.2, pwsh increased the default depth of json processing and added some json-based fixes.

Comment: If I do:

ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $taskAnswers, I get:

ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

Comment: If I do:

$taskAnswers | ConvertFrom-Json
       $answers = $taskAnswers | ConvertFrom-Json
       $answers[0].key
       $answers[0].value
       $answers[0].displayValue


I get:

Cannot index into a null array.

It's as if $taskAnswers has no data to pull back, but I can see it in inspect element:

taskAnswers: [{key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"},…]0: {key: "OtherCorrectName", value: "Pipeline", displayValue: "Pipeline"}

Comment: Oh, what is the output of `$xmlmcOutput.params.taskAnswers` by itself, and `$taskAnswers|gm`? I misread earlier. Chrome's tools aren't going to see the same requests - I get that it should have data, but that api can also just return an empty array like `TaskAnswers: [ ]`. Maybe you are missing a parameter that chrome is requesting?

Comment: $xmlmcOutput.params.taskAnswers by itself just gives me back an empty PowerShell prompt. $taskAnswers | gm returns gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.

Comment: @RobertGething then I'm pretty sure there is nothing there. A final step you can try is `$xmlmcOutput|Export-CliXml c:\temp\file.xml` and check the file for a complete definition of the object and its properties/values. You can try running `Invoke-HB-XMLMC` step by step to see if there is any issue - I found the definition here starting at line 310: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HornbillAPI/1.0.3/Content/HornbillAPI.psm1 . I also still recommend trying powershell core v7 if you haven't already.